# get_posts() does not return featured_image field on Wordpress custom endpoint

Tags: wordpress

Trying to get only the needed data on a custom endpoint in Wordpress. To do so, I am using `get_posts()` function.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'pages', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'wl_page',
  ]);
});


 function wl_page() {

  $args = [
    'numberposts' => 99999,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 0,
  ];

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  $data = [];

  $data['ID'] = $posts[0]->ID;
  $data['title'] = $posts[0]->post_title;
  $data['content'] = $posts[0]->post_content;
  $data['featured_image'] = $posts[0]->featured_media;

   return $data;
 }
```

It should return the ID of the featured image, but `get_posts()` doesn't even return that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_posts` returns array of Post Objects which don't have featured_media property available. Use `get_post_thumbnail_id()` instead.

See updated code below:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'pages', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'wl_page',
  ]);
});


 function wl_page() {

  $args = [
    'numberposts' => 99999,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 0,
  ];

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  $data = [];

  $data['ID'] = $posts[0]->ID;
  $data['title'] = $posts[0]->post_title;
  $data['content'] = $posts[0]->post_content;
  $data['featured_image'] = get_post_thumbnail_id( $posts[0]->ID );

   return $data;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the ID that way, but cannot retrieve the data with the function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`.

Comment: you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $posts[0]->ID, 'full')` It should give the URL of image.